# I want to create column with datatype as money in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, types, money-format

I have created a column in my PostgreSQL Database with datatype 'money'. I wanted to enter $7.9,$8.5,...kind of values into it. Now, I am getting error whenever I am trying to import data into it. Also, my default lc_monetary is 'ENGLIS INDIA.1252'. SInce, my datast has $ symbol into it, I wanted to change the same with 'en_US.UTF-8' but again I am getting error. Can you please help me and spot the mistake I am doing?

Comment: [Don't use `money`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money) it only has disadvantages (you just discovered one), but no real advantages. Use `decimal` or `float` instead and add the currency symbol when you display the value.

Comment: just read it as a string,  remove the `$` sign and save it as numeric

Comment: Did you set `lc_monetary` to the desired locale?